# How to insert a checkbox inside a input password field

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want my web page to display a check box inside the password field. User clicks on the check box and see the password as text. On un-check, its password again.

This is what I want. This is from the Ebay website login page.
[image]

This is what I am getting

[image]

I want this checkbox inside the password field. I could not find anything online on this topic.

Here is my code :

```
<!-- Set a password for the account -->
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin: 7px;">
    <input type="password" id="reg_password" name="reg_password" style="height: 35px;" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" ng-model="register_password" />
</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="eye" onclick="if(reg_password.type=='text')reg_password.type='password'; else reg_password.type='text';" />
```

Comment: I think you can do it by position property of css, Give the input element relative position, and checkbox absolute position, so that you can move checkbox in relation to input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add CSS and move your checkbox to one group div with input text.
See the example

```
#eye {
  position:absolute;
  right:50px;
  top:6px;
}
```

[Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/u6pexrg1/)

Comment: Thanks buddy.. Worked

Answer (score 1):

This would be the solution.

```css
.text-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 text-container" style="margin: 7px;">
  <input type="password" id="reg_password" name="reg_password" style="height: 35px;" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" ng-model="register_password" />
  <span id="btn" class="btn"><input type="checkbox" id="eye" onclick="if(reg_password.type=='text')reg_password.type='password'; else reg_password.type='text';" /></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
input#eye {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
#reg_password.form-control.input-lg {
    position: relative;
}
.parent{position:absolute;}
```

```html
<!-- Set a password for the account -->
<div class="col-md-12 parent" style="margin: 7px;">
    <input type="password" id="reg_password" name="reg_password" style="height: 35px;" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" ng-model="register_password" /> <input type="checkbox" id="eye" onclick="if(reg_password.type=='text')reg_password.type='password'; else reg_password.type='text';" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.text-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  transition: right 0.2s;
}

<div class="col-md-12 text-container" style="margin: 7px;">
  <input type="password" id="reg_password" name="reg_password" style="height: 35px;" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" ng-model="register_password" />
  <span id="btn" class="btn"><input type="checkbox" id="password" /></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#password").click(function () {
 if ($("#reg_password").attr("type")=="password") {
 $("#reg_password").attr("type", "text");
 }
 else{
 $("#reg_password").attr("type", "password");
 }

 });
 });
</script>
```