# How to add check boxes inside input

Tags: javascript, angular, html

I have a requirement to add check boxes inside input and scroll bar for input.

I have tried input but how to add check boxes.please help me on this.

Comment: Please check , hope this link will be helpful:-
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39784878/2919078)

Comment: Can you share the code that you have worked??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS::

```
.text-container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    .btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-container" style="margin: 7px;">
    <input type="password" id="reg_password" name="reg_password" style="height: 35px;" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" ng-model="register_password" />
    <span id="btn" class="btn"><input type="checkbox" id="eye" onclick="if(reg_password.type=='text')reg_password.type='password'; else reg_password.type='text';" /></span>
</div>
```

Please check the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784729/how-to-insert-a-checkbox-inside-a-input-password-field)